# Querying custom post type for all posts from logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to query a custom post type, for only the current logged in user.

My query runs, but it's returning records for ALL post_author's - not just the currently logged in one.

I have included Author in the setup of the custom post type (which is a POD):

[![PODAuthor][1]][1]

...and post_author is in the parent POST - however, Author is not in the metadata for the post (in post_meta):

[![postmeta][2]][2]

Does WP_Query not also query the posts table for author:

[![postauthor][3]][3]

Can anyone point me to what's wrong with my code below please?

Thanks, Mark

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$query_args = array(
  'post_type'             => 'tftracker',
  'post_author'           => $user_id,
  'order'                 => 'ASC',
  'orderby'               => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key'              => 'result_date',
  'nopaging'              => true,
'meta_query'       => array(
    array(
      'key'        => 'unit_type',
      'value'      => 'steps',
      'compare'    => '=',
    )
  )
);

$query = new WP_Query($query_args);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwIGd.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNllE.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEadx.png
```

Comment: Does your custom post type have `author` support? did you specify it in `supports` argument?

Comment: Hi Vijay - yes - I've added screenshots to my post, although the post_meta table in the database does not have meta data for Author - the parent POST table does.

Comment: Ok Thanks, the mistake is you're using `post_author` but it should be `author`, `post_author` will be used in `orderby` Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters

Comment: Thank you Vijay - that's it - if you add that, I'll mark it as the answer.  All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_author` is not a valid parameter for `WP_Query`

`author` is the correct one.

For more information on author parameters, Please check this [Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters)